# Mounting a 7-Speed Cassette on an 8/9 speed hub

Tags: wheels, gears, cassette, freewheel

I asked an [earlier question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13685/upgrading-wheels-on-a-vintage-peugeot-frame) regarding putting modern road wheels on my old steel frame.

After clarifying a few things the main issue to me is the number of gears on the freehub. (The freehub I'm considering takes an 8/9 speed and has a Shimano fitting). My bicycle is currently a 7-speed and uses a freewheel rather than a freehub.

So I think I have 2 options:

1. Put an 8-speed cassette on the new wheel and increase the number of gears on my bike. Issues: I assume an 8-speed uses a narrower chain; will my front chainring work with it?
2. Put on this [7-speed cassette](http://www.rosebikes.co.uk/article/shimano-cs-hg-50-cassette-7-speed/aid:414549/?origin=pla&kw=&gclid=CIiLuvrpprQCFXHLtAod3jQAXQ) which says it can work on an 8/9-speed hub with a [set](http://www.rosebikes.co.uk/article/shimano-8-speed-intermediate-ring-3-mm/aid:45835) of [spacer rings](http://www.rosebikes.co.uk/article/shimano-intermediate-ring-1-mm-steel/aid:44019). Questions: how do I use the spacer rings? Do I need only one of each for the whole cassette of one for each sprocket? Will this allow the slightly wider chain I currently use on the 7-speed.

Which option would be the better choice?

A few points to consider:

- Shifters are friction, so no need to consider indexing but I am unsure whether they have the range for an 8-speed (but with a narrower chain maybe the range is the same, just with smaller movements between gears)
- My deraileur is actually a modern Shimano 8/9 speed already (as the old one broke). I have adjusted it to suit my 7-speed with the limiter screws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have friction shifters and an 8/9 speed derailleur, you should be able to pop a 9 speed cassette on the back and use the full range.  You'll have to re-adjust your limit screws of course. Worst case, if that doesn't work, you may be able to remove one of the small cogs and space it out to use only 8 speeds.

The font chainrings will also likely be fine, usually you can go up/down one size without issue for front chainrings. Since your front chainring is designed for 8-speed, it will probably work fine with a 9-speed chain. I regularly use a 9-speed chainring in front with an otherwise all 10-speed setup without issues.

Comment: Great, think I'll opt for the 8-speed as I'm currently on a 7 and only going up one size is probably safer. Besides I don't feel the need for more than 8 on the back.

Answer (score 3):

I also use friction shifters, and recently put a 10 speed cassette onto my freehub - previously I had a seven. I put a 10 speed chain on as the chain walls are narrower. I have not yet changed the front chainrings, which are "eight speed".

In your case put on a chain to match your cassette. Seven speed cassettes usually have a spacer on the wheel side when used on a larger freehub.

It's always advisable to change the chain when you change the cassette anyway.

Comment: I intend to change the chain anyway. So I assume you have no problem with the narrower chain getting stuck between your front chainrings.

Comment: No problems at all with the set up - apart from the cost ...