# Cantilever brakes for older narrow fork bosses (55mm)?

Tags: brakes, fork, cyclocross

I have an 80s cyclocross frame I am restoring. The fork's cantilever bosses are spaced at 55mm - much narrower than the modern standard (around 70mm I believe).

I tried to fit a pair of Tektro CR-720s, but despite using thinner pads and removing the spacers cannot get the pads to square with the rim.

Can anyone recommend a set of modern cantilevers (preferably wide profile) alternative to Mafacs that they known to work with this narrow spacing?

I'm hopeful the [Dia Compe GC-999](http://www.diacompe.com.tw/product_View.asp?nid=988) might do the trick as they seem to be based on a traditional design.

I also e-mailed Velo-Orange and Paul Components as I thought they had cantilevers that would match, but they claimed theirs don't work at this narrow spacing.

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/dia-compe-brakes-for-1991-bridgestone-rb-t

Comment: I've had this exact same problem (and I've also emailed VO and Paul with the same answer!)

Comment: Thanks, that thread certainly covers the same issue, but I can't see any modern replacements recommended... I have been looking at the [Dia Comp GC-999](http://www.diacompe.com.tw/product_View.asp?nid=988), [Dia Compe CRX](http://www.diacompe.com.tw/product_View.asp?nid=989), and [TRP EuroX](http://www.trpbrakes.com/category.php?catid=185) and emailed the manufacturers maybe they'll get back to me regarding spacing. All these use the old post style as opposed to the modern threaded v-brake pads, maybe there is more room to maneuver with that design if the geometry otherwise fits.

Comment: My solution is to use the [planet-x frogs bollox](http://www.planetx.co.uk/i/q/BCPXFRBO/planet-x-frogs-bollox-cantilever-brakeset) with Kool Stop narrow pads - it's tight but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the [Planet X Frogs Bollox set](http://www.on-one.co.uk/i/q/BCPXFRBO/planet_x_frogs_bollox_cantilever_brakeset) suggested [here](http://www.bikeforums.net/showthread.php/922675-Issues-with-27-quot-wheels-and-Tektro-CR720-Canitlever-Brakes) (I've also seen the Empella Froglegs suggested as an option). Another option is to find another old 80s bike for cheap and rip the canti's off them as suggested by [this thread](http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-916014.html).

Comment: I emailed PlanetX and they said their cantilevers were designed for use with modern spaced forks - of course this is probably just their safest reply.

Comment: Ah - I see that thread has been updated since I last checked and it appears they have worked out OK for that guy. I will look into it - thanks

Comment: He also claims the TRP EuroX will work too, but they're far more expensive (40 bucks vs 140 bucks...), but at 40 bucks theres not much to lose.

Comment: I am also not sure if he's using Kool Stop Thinlines as well, but they look like the regular Kool Stop Salmons for canti's.

Answer (score 1):

What brake pads did you try? I had a heck of a time getting modern Tektro cantis working on a fork of mine until I used Kool Stop Thinlines with the spacers set for in their thinnest configuration.

Comment: This might better serve as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: They are Kool Stop v-type I think, might look into these thin lines, so thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Alan Gerber (if you're still around) do you know the post spacing? I'd love to get a set of Tektros working on an old Trek with 55 or 60 mm spacing.

Comment: I crashed that bike and destroyed the fork, so I can't say, but the Kool Stops are $12 or less, so they're probably worth buying as an experiment.